# What is the protocol to open Software Center with installation page for a selected application?

Tags: apt, software-installation, software-center, url, apturl

I need to add install buttons which must open up Ubuntu Software Center with a pre-selected application. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to do it!
I've found this by going through the inspect element console in the [apps.ubuntu.com](http://apps.ubuntu.com) website.
And its easier than expected.Just need to know the real name of the software you want to open in software center !
Just add this code on the place of the url (This can't be done without editing the code in HTML)
  `apt://`
This apt:// code tells ubuntu when the user clicks the button to open Ubuntu software center.
And if you want to install a specific software, then add the software name just after it.
Like this `apt://openshot` !!
Isn't it easy ?
Then do it !